# Parse PFQuery IOS return username

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm really stuck trying to do something that I think is simple.

I'm using Parse, I have 2 Classes, `Users` and `Posts`. `Posts` contain a pointer to the `Users` table.  I am able to return the object from `Posts` in the form of `user = PFUser:5ifTaddiOU\\`. Instead of that, I'm trying to get the actual `username` of that `pfuser` which is `Stan Brady`.

Can anyone help on **how I could retrieve the `username` of that object?**

This is how I'm querying parse

```
- (void) retrieveFromParse{
    PFQuery *retrieveStories = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];


    [retrieveStories findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"%@",objects);

        if (!error) {
            storyArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [storyTableView reloadData];
    }];

}
```

Retrieval

```
PFObject *tempObject = [storyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"user"];
```

My log shows the return value of `user = PFUser:5ifTaddiOU";\n}`. I'm looking for `username = Stan Brady` in the log . I've also tried `cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"user.username"];`  but that returns `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a `PFQuery` won't fetch the actual objects from a relationship, only a reference to them.

Try telling your query to include the user object:

```
PFQuery *retrieveStories = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
[retrieveStories includeKey:@"user"];
```

You will hopefully then be able to do:

```
cell.cellTitle.text = [[tempObject objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"username"];
```

Comment: Great, that did it.  I was totally misunderstanding but now it's clear as day.  Thanks Mr. Frost